# last time a filesystem was checked?

Tags: linux, filesystems

What command can tell me the last time that a filesystem was fsck'd?  A date would be nice, but I'd settle for the mount count since the last fsck.

I've looked all around for this in fsck*, lsattr, and stat, and I don't see it.

Answer (score 22):

tune2fs -l gives you that information for ex.

`sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sda1 | grep "Last checked"`

Comment: this will only work on  ext2/ext3/ext4 filesystems.

Answer (score 9):

You can use [tune2fs](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl8_tune2fs.htm) to get the information

```
tune2fs -l /dev/devicetocheck | grep "Last Checked"
```

Similarly you can get the mount count

```
tune2fs -l /dev/devicetocheck | grep "Mount Count"
```

Comment: For Debian Jessie (tune2fl version 1.42.12), the correct `grep` argument for the second command listed above is `"Mount count"`

Answer (score 7):

Apart from `tune2fs -l`, `dumpe2fs` will also give you this information:

```
dumpe2fs /dev/sda1 | grep "Last Checked"
dumpe2fs /dev/sda1 | grep "Mount Count"
```

Answer (score 6):

Thanks everyone!  And for reiserfs I found that `debugreiserfs` shows the mount count and last fsck run date.

Answer (score 0):

if one uses lvm

```
tune2fs -l /dev/sda5 | egrep -i "mount count|Check interval|Last|Next"
```

will fail with:

```
tune2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sda5
```

one will have to do like this:

```
tune2fs -l /dev/hostname-vg/root | egrep -i "mount count|Check interval|Last|Next"
Last mounted on:          /
Last mount time:          Wed Sep  4 17:45:12 2019
Last write time:          Wed Sep  4 17:45:10 2019
Mount count:              20
Maximum mount count:      -1
Last checked:             Fri Aug 30 16:09:19 2019
Check interval:           0 (<none>)
```